# How to prevent single quote on insert sql?

Tags: sql, go

I'm trying to insert as such:

```
query := `INSERT INTO logs (event_raw) FORMAT JSONEachRow {"event_raw": "?"}
_, err := s.db.ExecContext(ctx, query, event)
```

Where event is a string:

```
{\"id\":\"abcdefgh\"}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error because `?` is replaced with `'{\"id\":\"abcdefgh\"}'` (wrapped with single quotes)

How can I prevent this behavior and just have: `{"event_raw": "{\"id\":\"abcdefgh\"}"}`  ?

Comment: Can you provide a fuller example showing what database you're working with and tag that specific database here? Placeholder arguments like this are typically parsed an sanitized by the database, and your database might not supported a nested JSON argument like this.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment, but you might try:

```golang
query := "INSERT INTO logs (event_raw) FORMAT JSONEachRow ?"
arg := fmt.Sprintf(`{"event_raw": "%s"}`, event)
_, err := s.db.ExecContext(ctx, query, arg)
```